# How to assign array values to php variable

Tags: php

In the following code how to assign array values to a php variable.

```
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
$cutomername[] = $objResult["firstname"];
$mailid[] = $objResult["mailid"];
$address[] = $objResult["address"];
$phonenumber[] = $objResult["phonenumber"];
$items[] = $objResult["itemname"];
$quantity[] = $objResult["quantity"];
$total[] = $objResult["grandtotal"];

    $name = $cutomername[];
    $mail = $mailid[];
    $addr = $address[];
    $phnum = $phonenumber[];
    $itm = $items[];
    $qty = $quantity[];
    $tot = $total[];
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question, what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Eineki want to assign each value in a array to a variable to store it in database.i got the solution.

Comment: @Aravin You are just *reading* values **from** a database. Definitely you are not storing them. At least if you don't do it later in your code

Comment: @Eineki i have a code below while loop for store values to DB. But i didn't mention here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign your two variables at once using something like this:

```
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
  $name = $cutomername[] = $objResult["firstname"];
  $mail = $mailid[] = $objResult["mailid"];
  $addr = $address[] = $objResult["address"];
  $phnum = $phonenumber[] = $objResult["phonenumber"];
  $itm = $items[] = $objResult["itemname"];
  $qty = $quantity[] = $objResult["quantity"];
  $tot = $total[] = $objResult["grandtotal"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer perfectly working can you say the reason why my code is not working.

Comment: `$name = $cutomername[];` inserts a new `null` value at the end of the `$cutomername` array, and then it assigns that `null` value to `$name`.

Comment: thank you to solve my doubt.

Comment: So as it turns out, `$name = $cutomername[];` is a fatal syntax error. It appears that my understanding was incorrect in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $customername[count($customername)-1];
```

And so forth for every variable.

Alternatively, you could store length before assigning `$total` like that

```
$len = count($customername)-1;
```

And then for every variable just write like that:

```
$name = $customername[$len];
```

Comment: Or you can just use `$name = end($customername);` but it will be overwritten with the next iteration loop.

Comment: @Eineki Do you per chance know how fast `end()` works? I mean, does it iterate to the end of array or not?

Comment: No, it does not iterate at all, internally `end` uses `zend_hash_internal_pointer_end` that use a pointer to identify the end of the hash it manage (just read from the php 5.4.16 sources)